# Android:Google Map not displaying

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-signing

I had outsourced an application which has google maps in it.The developer gave me apk which works fine and google map is also displayed.But when i run the source code in android studio google map is not visible.In manifest there are two api_keys debug and release.I commented the debug key and generated signed apk ,but still the map is not visible.Is the issue related with signing of app?

Comment: are you using emulator or a realdevice

Comment: @UmarAta:real device

Comment: okay do you have google console credentials, login and check does your app is there and the api key is same as mentioned in your app source code

Comment: No. Actually the developer who developed the app must be having it.

Comment: no problem then, he can share the credentials with you and another thing is that you need to also upload you development machine sha fingerprints to make apk from your machine and work